# Regex and preg_replace: How to match the same pattern multiple times in URL

Tags: regex, url, tags, preg-replace

I want to use REGEX to target the CITE tag in two different ways, depending on if it is in a URL or not:

- Either remove the tag if it is in a URL, starting with www or http(s);
- Leave the tag in tact if it is not in an URL

This is the string I want to operate on:

```
www.os<cite>map</cite>s.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/os<cite>map</cite>s/
and the normal text <cite>map</cite> here and again <cite>map</cite> here
http://os<cite>map</cite>s.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/os<cite>map</cite>s/
and the normal text <cite>map</cite> here and again <cite>map</cite> here
```

I have been using this expression:

```
$this_record = preg_replace('/((www.)|(https?:\/\/))([^\s]*?)(<cite>([^\s]*?)<\/cite>)([^\s]*)/', '$2$3$4$6$7', $this_record);
```

This works, but only for the the FIRST set of  tags and results in:

```
www.osmaps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/os<cite>map</cite>s/
and the normal text <cite>map</cite> here and again <cite>map</cite> here
http://osmaps.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/os<cite>map</cite>s/
and the normal text <cite>map</cite> here and again <cite>map</cite> here
```

Only the first set of  tags are removed in the URLs. How would I remove subsequent ones?

Many thanks

Comment: Your regular expression asks for `http` or `www` to start the string, but the second match in the same url starts after the end of the first match, where it does not find that starting token. You might just want to run it multiple times, until the string is no longer modified, to catch all instances within a given URL.

Comment: Thanks for that! Yes I was beginning to think that was the only way to do it